# Integrating $(x^2-1)(y^2+1)dx+(x-1)(y+2)dy=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm stuck on solving the following differential equation: $$(x^2-1)(y^2+1)dx+(x-1)(y+2)dy=0$$

Obviously it's not exact, because $\frac{d((x^2-1)(y^2+1))}{dy}\neq\frac{d((x-1)(y+2))}{dx}$. So we have to find an integrating factor.

I've been taught how to find an integrating factor depending on: $\mu(x), \mu(y), \mu(x+y), \mu(x-y),  \mu(xy),$ but I've been 1h trying each case and it's none of the cases above. I don't think they want me to find a different integrating factor, so I guess I'm doing something wrong.

Once I have the integrating factor I know how to solve it, so I'd really appreciate any hint to be able to continue.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is this the way your differential equation was given? Because this form doesn't imply that $y$ is a function of $x$ unless that assumption is implicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{x^{2}-1}{x-1}dx+\dfrac{y+2}{y^{2}+1}dy&=0\\
(x+1)dx+\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{2y}{y^{2}+1}dy+2\dfrac{1}{1+y^{2}}dy&=0\\
\int(x+1)dx+\dfrac{1}{2}\int\dfrac{2y}{y^{2}+1}dy+2\int\dfrac{1}{1+y^{2}}dy&=0\\
\dfrac{1}{2}x^{2}+x+\dfrac{1}{2}\log(y^{2}+1)+2\tan^{-1}y&=C
\end{align*}

Comment: Do we have to deal with $x-1=0$ since we're dividing by it?

Comment: I wondered that too, but what is the main lost if we disregard that? Then the function $y$ may not be differentiable at $x=1$, that's it.

Answer (score 2):

$$(x^2-1)(y^2+1)dx+(x-1)(y+2)dy=0$$ is separable so you can solve it with little effort.